# I converted my .py into .exe using pyinstaller and py-to-exe but i am getting error while executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyinstaller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDBxn.jpg)

Error image and code snip have been attached. I have created exe using py-to-exe and pyinstaller but not able to run please help me to make this exe as executable.

```
if os.path.exists("ResultCRMDailyFile.csv"): os.remove("ResultCRMDailyFile.csv") else: time.sleep(5) data = pd.read_csv("CRMDailyFile.csv", names= col_names, skiprows=[0], encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') data.insert(3, column="UTCDclDate_c", value=data["UTCAppDate_c"]) data["UTCAppDate_c"] = np.where(data["ApprovedDeclined_c"] == 'Approved', data["UTCAppDate_c"], '') data["UTCDclDate_c"] = np.where(data["ApprovedDeclined_c"] == 'Declined', data["UTCDclDate_c"], '') data = data.to_csv("ResultCRMDailyFile.csv", index=False) print(data.head())
```

Comment: Have you Googled the error?  What else have you tried?

Comment: Create the exe using the `--console` mode and check for errors (if any) that occur during the execution and paste the traceback here for us to help identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that python is added to the `PATH`.

And run the following in your terminal

```
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py -w --icon=iconFileName.ico
```

`-w` and `icon` are optional.

`-w` is to remove the black screen (console/ terminal window) while launching the `.exe` file

`icon` is used to set an icon for your `.exe` file